# Rails 3, menu in layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

i have some controllers, i want to put categories names into layout, like menu, what i could see in all pages. Is there a easy sollution to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use : render :layout => 'yourcustomlayout'
in your specific action.

Answer (score 0):

Use general layout for whole application. You can specify one layout for an application and even override it wherever required.

[See here for details](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) and [near exact example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-layouts.htm) for your case.

Comment: I have like this <a href="http://s972.photobucket.com/albums/ae204/aidzas/?action=view&amp;current=layout.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="http://i972.photobucket.com/albums/ae204/aidzas/layout.jpg" border="0" alt="Photobucket"></a> and there is main in yellow background, this is from app/view/layout, i want to add categories names there is yellow background

Comment: Yes. See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-layouts.htm . Almost exactly what you wanted (without much colors)